# `re.sub(pattern, functor, string)` for C++

Tags: c++, regex, string, std

Python regexp has a useful feature, the ability to use function to determine the replacement. That is, `re.sub(pattern, functor, string)` will pass the match result to the functor to obtain a replacement string to use. This is much more flexible than the format string syntax that uses `\1', '\2' to refer to submatch.

Now, I want to achieve the same thing in C++, and I am not sure how to do it. The first idea is to use `std::regex_replace`, but it has no overloads that allow passing a functor. Another idea is to use a iterator that split the text into tokens with type `MATCH` or `NOT_MATCH`, but it seems that the standard regex iterator returns only one type. They either skip all the non-matches, or they skip all the matches.

Is there any way to do it? I prefer the standard library.

Comment: For any future readers, `boost::regex` seems to have such overloads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.prefix()` of the match result to get the non-matching prefix part of the string, and `.suffix()` to get the non-matching rest of the string.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/01327d6483a49d9b) (adapted from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator)).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a blog post about this topic here: http://blog.brainstembreakfast.com/update/c++/2014/09/20/regex-replace-ext/

The function you are looking for is

```
template< class Traits, class CharT,
        class STraits, class SAlloc >
  inline std::basic_string<CharT,STraits,SAlloc> 
  regex_replace_ext( const std::basic_string<CharT,STraits,SAlloc>& s,
             const std::basic_regex<CharT,Traits>& re,
             const typename std::common_type<std::function<std::basic_string<CharT,STraits,SAlloc> 
             (const unsigned, const std::basic_string<CharT,STraits,SAlloc> &)>>::type& fmt,
              std::regex_constants::match_flag_type flags =
              std::regex_constants::match_default)
  {
    std::vector<int> smatches{-1};
    if(re.mark_count() == 0)
    smatches.push_back(0);
    else
      {
    smatches.resize(1+re.mark_count());
    std::iota(std::next(smatches.begin()), smatches.end(), 1); //-1, 1, 2, etc...    
      }

    unsigned smatch_count = smatches.size();
    unsigned count = 0;

    std::regex_token_iterator
      <typename std::basic_string<CharT,STraits,SAlloc>::const_iterator> 
      tbegin(s.begin(), s.end(), re, smatches, flags), tend;            

    std::basic_stringstream<CharT,STraits,SAlloc> ret_val;
    std::for_each(tbegin, tend, [&count,&smatch_count,&ret_val,&fmt]
          (const std::basic_string<CharT,STraits,SAlloc> & token)
          {
            if(token.size() != 0)
              {
            if(!count) 
              ret_val << token;
            else
              ret_val << fmt(count,token);
              }
            count = ++count % smatch_count;
          });
    return ret_val.str();
  }
```

Usage:

```
    const std::string bss("{Id_1} [Fill_0] {Id_2} [Fill_1] {Id_3} {Id_4} {Id_5}.");
    const std::regex re("(\\{.*?\\})|(\\[.*?\\])");
    using dictionary = std::map<std::string,std::string>;
    const std::vector<const dictionary> dict
      {
    {
      {"{Id_1}","This"},
      {"{Id_2}","test"},
      {"{Id_3}","my"},
      {"{Id_4}","favorite"},
      {"{Id_5}","hotdog"}
    },
    {
      {"[Fill_0]","is a"},
      {"[Fill_1]","of"}
    }
      };

    auto fmt1 = [&dict](const unsigned smatch, const std::string & s)->std::string
      {
        auto dict_smatch = smatch - 1;
        if(dict_smatch > dict.size()-1)
           return s; //more submatches than expected

        const auto it = dict[dict_smatch].find(s); 
        return it != dict[dict_smatch].cend() ? it->second : s;
      };

    std::string modified_string = regex_replace_ext(bss, re, fmt1);
```